# Handle multiple connector in one mule application using mule domain project

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I have an application which consist of two http connector with different host and port. How to handle it with shared resource i.e. mule domain project.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/shared-resources.

The general idea is simple:
 1. Create a domain project (in AnypointStudio: New -> Mule Domain project)
 2. Move your connector configuration from the project to the domain project (use cut/paste in XML, not the graphical editor)
 3. Reference the domain project from your Mule project (property domain in mule-deploy.properties

And don't forget for deployment: The domain must be deployed before you deploy your project.

Comment: This is for single connector. kindly understand my query. I have two http connectors with different port i.e. 8081 and 8082 respectively. How i will do with domain project. If i will cut and paste for both http listener then how it will recognize which connector for which port. @Rogar

Answer (score 0):

@Kishan Kumar Soni, The referenced documentation explains on how use the `Shared Resources` with mule and is not meant for single connector only. You can move your two `http:listener-config` into shared resources config(domain-config) file, make sure to have unique name, then reference them in your application(s) as desired. It will work.

Comment: Lets I have added both http:listener-config in shared folder. In my application, one has path /test1 and /test2 respectively then tell me that how will my paths recognize the http:listener-config from shared folder. I want path /test1 will be referenced on 8081 port and /test2 path will be referenced on 8082 port. @Anil

Comment: @KishanKumarSoni, lets say you have 2 listeners defined inside the shared config like this `<http:listener-config name="Shared_HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <http:listener-config name="Shared_HTTP_Listener_Configuration2" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>` and in in the app select `Shared_HTTP_Listener_Configuration` for app` and select `Shared_HTTP_Listener_Configuration2` for app2 byt doing this both apps listening on different ports as desired. Hope this helps.